# How to calculate time average from a array list

Tags: perl, date

I have a time array list in format h:mm:ss. I want to calculate the average time of this array.

I tried below code but there is some problem with the packages. I successfully installed Duration package but now complier is throwing error on Duration::Parse package.

PS: I am using Dwinperl as the editor on windows.

```
use Time::Duration::Parse qw(parse_duration);
use Time::Duration qw(duration);
use List::Util qw(sum);
my $count = @time;
my $sum   = sum map {parse_duration($_) } @time;
my $avg   = $sum / $count;

print duration($sum, 3), "--Total Time\n";
print duration($avg, 3), "--Avg Time\n";
```

this is the error message that I am getting.

```
Can't locate Time/Duration/Parse.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Dwimperl/perl/sit
e/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at time.pl line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at time.pl line 7.
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to give us the error message!

Comment: updated the error comments

Comment: Either you didn't install Time::Duration::Parse successfully, or you explicitly directed its installation to a nonstandard directory (using `PREFIX=` or some such) and you didn't tell Perl to look into that directory (using `use lib` or env var `PERL5LIB`).

Comment: It could also be a permission issue accessing Time/Duration/Parse.pm, but not that's likely on Windows.

Comment: Where is that file located on your computer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems `perl` could not find package `Time::Duration::Parse` installed within list of ***@INC*** paths

Type following command in terminal to check if `perl` can find your module by default

```
perldoc -l Time::Duration::Parse
```

If above command didn't give you installed location of desired module,

1. Make sure you have installed required modules
2. try adding following line to your `perl` code to add custom installed path of module

   `use lib '/path/to/module';`